# PDE unique solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the Cauchy problem for a fully nonlinear pde, we take the integral surface passing through a initial curve, $\Gamma$, with the parametric equations: $x = f(s)$, $y=g(s)$, and $z=h(s)$.

We assume $f,g,h \: \epsilon \: C^{1}$ for $s$ near a value $s_{0}$ corresponding to a point $\: p_{0} = (f(s_{0}),g(s_{0}),h(s_{0}))$. We have to find the functions $p = \Phi (s)$ and $q = \psi (s)$ such that, $h'(s) = \Phi (s) f'(s) + \psi (s) g'(s)$ and $F(f(s),g(s),h(s), \Phi (s), \psi (s))=0$.

My Question is then:$\:$ Given some special solution $p_{0}, q_{0}$ of

(1) $\:h'(s_{0}) = q_{0}f'(s_{0})+q_{0}g'(s_{0})$ and $\: F(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0},p_{0},q_{0}) =0$

such that,

(2) $\: \Delta =f'(s_{0})F_{q}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0},p_{0},q_{0}) - g'(s_{0})F_{q}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0},p_{0},q_{0}) \neq 0$

How could I then show that a unique function(s) solve (1) under the condition of (2)? Thank you.

Edit: Grammar

Comment: I can but the problem is that I don't know how to show that a unique function solves this with a rigorous proof @Harry49

Comment: @Harry49 I proved this using the implicit function theorem.